# When I tried to Create a table in MySql 5.0,it was Showing error 1064.What does it mean?How Can I resolve those error?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `reg`.`offerpoolride` (
  `frooffer` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `tffer` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `datoffer` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `timoffer` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `vehicleoffer` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `modeloffer` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `carconditioningoffer` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `mapersonsoffer` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `mileageoffer` VARCHAR NOT NULL
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz give the size of the columns with `VARCHAR` too.
Such as `VARCHAR(20)`.